# How to detect an object after the sobel detection in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, object-detection

Is there anyway to detect a car (object) after a sobel detction in opencv?

This is my current's work as shown as the image below:

[image]

Advanced thanks for any guidelines or solutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object detection task need quite a bit of effort.
First, extract relevant features from object you want to detect: histogram of oriented gradient should be fine for car detection. So, you need to get database of car images. Second, you need to learn models using machine learning algorithm. Boosting or support vector machine should do the work. You will find the implementation in opencv.

Comment: Adding references to your suggestions will improve a lot the quality of your answers.

Comment: yea do you have any references ? Thanks!

Comment: You should read the paper "Histograms of Oriented Gradients for Human Detection" written by Dalal & Triggs (2005).